# Request header field … is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: django, reactjs, express, webpack, django-rest-framework

I use react/express with django as backend.
I am trying to integrate s3 fine uploader and i am getting this issue :Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response when trying to get signature from django,in a post request.
Normally i make all my request in code using fetch but here i make use of the package https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader and it make use of xhr ? any one ran into this issue

**Synopsis**

ERROR: Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Frontend:React/express/webpack
Backend:Dajngo
Environment:Local (django server,react local api)
cause: xhr?

Answer (score 15):

Your problem is in the backend. Seems like the api you are trying to use is written in django.

The api owner needs to explicitly add that header into the CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS settings. I had the same issue with the Content-Disposition header while uploading images. This is my settings:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ('content-disposition', 'accept-encoding',
                      'content-type', 'accept', 'origin', 'authorization')
```

In your case, that setting needs to include 'cache-control'.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to enable `cors` while initializing Fine Uploader.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FineUploaderTraditional from 'fine-uploader-wrappers'
import Gallery from 'react-fine-uploader'

// ...or load this specific CSS file using a <link> tag in your document
import 'react-fine-uploader/gallery/gallery.css'

const uploader = new FineUploaderTraditional({
    options: {
        chunking: {
            enabled: true
        },
        cors: {
            //all requests are expected to be cross-domain requests
            expected: true,
            //if you want cookies to be sent along with the request
            sendCredentials: true
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: true,
            endpoint: '/uploads'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: '/uploads'
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true
        }
    }
})

class UploadComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Gallery uploader={ uploader } />
        )
    }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/CORS.html) for details.